# conditional replacement within strings of pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, string, pandas, replace, slice

Say I've got a column in my Pandas Dataframe that looks like this:

```
s = pd.Series(["ab-cd.", "abc", "abc-def/", "ab.cde", "abcd-"])
```

I would like to use this column for fuzzy matching and therefore I want to remove characters ('.' , '/' , '-') but only at the end of each string so it looks like this:

```
s = pd.Series(["ab-cd", "abc", "abc-def", "ab.cde", "abcd"])
```

So far I started out easy so instead of generating a list with characters I want removed I just repeated commands for different characters like:

```
if s.str[-1] == '.':
  s.str[-1].replace('.', '')
```

But this simply produces an error. How do I get the result I want, that is strings without characters at the end (characters in the rest of the string need to be preserved)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace with regex will help you get the output

```
s.replace(r'[./-]$','',regex=True)
```

or with the help of apply incase looking for an alternative

```
s.apply(lambda x :x[:-1] if x[-1] is '.' or '-' or '/' else x)
```

```
0      ab-cd
1        abc
2    abc-def
3     ab.cde
4       abcd
dtype: object
```

Comment: Glad to help @MichielV. . If my answer was helpful, don't forget accept it - click on the check mark (✓) beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. Happy learning.

Answer (score 0):

You can use str.replace with a regex:

```
>>> s = pd.Series(["ab-cd.", "abc", "abc-def/", "ab.cde", "abcd-"])
>>> s.str.replace("\.$|/$|\-$","")
0      ab-cd
1        abc
2    abc-def
3     ab.cde
4       abcd
dtype: object
>>>
```

which can be reduced to this:

```
>>> s.str.replace("[./-]$","")
0      ab-cd
1        abc
2    abc-def
3     ab.cde
4       abcd
dtype: object
>>>
```

Comment: Many thanks to you MedAli, I can now continue my project!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html#pandas-series-str-replace) with a regular expression

```
s.str.replace(r'[./-]$','')
```

Substitute inside `[./-]` any characters you want to replace. `$` means the match should be at the end of the string.

To replace "in-place" use [`Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html)

```
s.replace(r'[./-]$','', inplace=True, regex=True)
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, this solved my problem right away!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to remove characters from the end of strings in a column in a pandas DataFrame with the following line of code:

```
s.replace(r'[./-]$','',regex=True)
```

Where all entries in between brackets ( [./-] ) indicate characters to be removed and $ indicate they should be removed from the end